# How to generate a random flood fill of cells with various sizes in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

In 2 dimensional space I need to create a special kind of flood fill method that would generate a random array based on a set of predefined objects, the red, blue, green, and yellow objects in the image below.

edit: No single "fill object" should overlap another and their placement should appear to be random but it would be fine to add some sort of probability of occurrence for each object.  Maybe even place all of the objects except the red 1x1 and until a certain capacity is met, and then fill in the rest with the red.

[image]

Now imagine a random result that would like the following.

edit: The result image I have provided shows that everything is always separated with red squares, This could certainly be possible, but not a necessary part of the scope.  I drew the image this way in order to eliminate any notion that some color object aside from red is considered "joinable" to other like colored objects.  In other words, I didn't want people to think that a 3x3 green object could become a 6x3, as part of the algorithm.  It should be treated as a two separate 3x3s that were placed next to each other randomly.  To address @jdweng comment, part of the solution could very well entail adding some sort of probability of occurrence field to the FillObject class, and then always treat the 1x1 red squares as the object that makes up space.

[image]

Here is the code I have come up with so far. I'm having a tough time thinking this one through to the end.  I'm familiar with a standard flood fill, but I'm not sure how to make that work with the randomly sized "fill objects".

```
//Defined objects that make up the grid fill
public class FillObject
{
    public int xDim { get; set; }
    public int yDim { get; set; }

    public string color { get; set; }

    public FillObject(int x, int y, string c)
    {
        xDim = x;
        yDim = y;
        color = c;
    }
}

//container for information about a position on the grid
public class GridPosition
{
    public int xPosition { get; set; }
    public int yPosition { get; set; }

    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class GridGenerator
{
    //declare the intitial possible fill objects
    public static FillObject[] fillObjects = new FillObject[]
    {
        new FillObject(1, 1, "red"),
        new FillObject(2, 2, "blue"),
        new FillObject(3, 3, "green"),
        new FillObject(4, 4, "yellow")
    };

    //Generic list of grid positions
    public List<GridPosition> grid = new List<GridPosition>();

    //Method to generate random grid filled with the fill objects
    public void GenerateGrid(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {
        //Iterate through grid and set each "cell" to a color based on the original fill objects
        for(int x = startX; x <= endX; x += 1)
        {
            for(int y = startY; y <= endY; y += 1)
            {
                grid.Add(new GridPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have considered just running through the for loop and testing the list for already created positions and then using a random chance to "drop" in the fill objects if they can fit, but it seems rather inefficient to test the list every loop iteration for the existence of a populated position and then there would also be an issue with testing for offsets for each object.  Possibly a recursive method that starts with the largest "fillObject" and then recursively tests and fills, but again it just seems very cumbersome.  Is there some clever way of doing this in one loop of the grid that I'm not seeing?

edit: Here are the explicit goals

- Create a method that generates a List object that
  contains every position on a grid.
- Each grid position should contain the position as int x and int y as 
  fields in the GridPosition class.
- The generated GridPosition objects should should honor the original
  FillObject structures.
- Probability of occurrence for each object is fine, and everything
  left over can be filled with red 1x1 objects.
- Objects of the same color, can be adjacent(even though the result
  image doesn't show this)
- Ideally this is done in a single pass(like a flood fill), but
  recursion is another possibility.
- True randomness isn't necessary, it just needs to look somewhat
  random, but there should also not be the appearance of patterns.

Comment: So given a bunch of random filled squares, you want to flood fill a larger space with them, and not ovewrite anything that is there

Comment: or.. You want to distribute random shapes in a larger image?

Comment: What is the criteria for generating the random objects?  Not all random objects are the same.  My probability teacher kept on asking the same question.  If I had a deck of cards that were perfectly shuffled and I shuffled the deck one more time.  Would the deck be more or less random?  In your case, is it better to have more yellow, green or blue objects? If you 2-D space was only 5x5 what would the optimal random results look like?

Comment: Yeah i call shenanigans, it seems like an interesting question, but you fell down with specifics.. or lack there of

Comment: Step 1: A clear description of the rules and goals.

Comment: A kind of `battleship game` field generation?

Comment: @TheGeneral first comment is the intended behavior.  I will edit and attempt to clarify.

Comment: @MBo The Battleship analogy is pretty good.  It is for a procedural generation of structures in a 3d environment, but I have simplified it quite a bit for these purposes.

Comment: If you know the objects ahead of time, for each object you want to place in the grid, determine the set of all squares it could be placed on, and choose one randomly. If you don't know it ahead of time, generate a random object and follow the same algorithm.

Comment: Is there anything else on this grid to start with, also are the insertable objects all square? if its clear, you could just iterate left to right top to bottom, choose a random object to draw (if it fits, by scanning the area needed for that object), place,  then starting at the next x (or next x/y). A Modified flood fill would also work, however you would have to also scan and push the extents of the objects to the queue, and probably do a an 8 way fill on those extents just to make sure you are filling everything. I think a fill would be more computationally expensive than the former

Comment: @GeoJohn is this what you actually wanted?

Comment: @TheGeneral Your answer is beyond perfect, and very fast... Mad skillz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i had a free hour this morning so i had a stab at this. To make it fast i used `unsafe`, `fixed` and pointers. I am not sure whether you wanted an image or not, however this can be used with just a multi dimensional array as well.

**FillObject**

```
public class FillObject
{
   public FillObject(int width, Color color)
   {
      Width = width;
      Color = color.ToArgb();
   }

   public int Color { get; set; }

   public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension Methods**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static Color NextColor(this Random r) => Color.FromArgb(r.Next(256), r.Next(256), r.Next(256));

   public static FillObject GetObject(this List<FillObject> objects, int maxSize, Random rand)
   {
      var nextObjs = objects.Where(o => o.Width <= maxSize)
                              .ToList();
      return nextObjs[rand.Next(nextObjs.Count)];
   }
}
```

**Helper Method**

```
public static unsafe bool GetMaxSize(int x, int y, Size size, int* array, int pad, out int maxSize)
{

   maxSize = 0;

   //we cant be within pad distance of anything else or the edges
   for (var y2 = y - pad; y2 < y + pad; y2++)
      for (var x2 = x - pad; x2 < x + pad; x2++)
         if (y2 < 0 || x2 < 0 || y2 >= size.Height || x2 >= size.Width || *(array + x2 + y2 * size.Width) != 0)
            return false;

   // so what do we have left
   for (var y2 = y - pad; y2 < y + 1; y2++)
   {
      var max = maxSize > 0 ? maxSize : _largest + pad;
      maxSize = 0;
      for (var x2 = x; x2 < size.Width && x2 < x + max; x2++, maxSize++)
         if (*(array + x2 + y2 * size.Width) != 0)
            break;
   }

   // safety first
   maxSize = Math.Min(maxSize - pad, Math.Min(size.Width - x - pad, size.Height - y - pad));

   return maxSize > 0;
}
```

**Main Method**

```
public static unsafe void Generate(Size size, int* array, int pad)
{
   for (var y = 0 + pad; y < size.Height; y++)
      for (var x = 0 + pad; x < size.Width; x++)
      {
         // no maxSize bail
         if (!GetMaxSize(x, y, size, array, pad, out var maxSize))
            continue;

         // pick a random one
         var nextObj = _objects.GetObject(maxSize, _rand);

         // draw the thing
         for (var y2 = y; y2 < y + nextObj.Width; y2++)
            for (var x2 = x; x2 < x + nextObj.Width; x2++)
               *(array + x2 + y2 * size.Width) = nextObj.Color;

         // start again outside that width
         // remembering the loop will increment this anyway 
         x += nextObj.Width + pad - 1;
      }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{

   _objects = Enumerable.Range(0, 25)
                        .Select((i, i1) => new FillObject(i, _rand.NextColor()))
                        .ToList();

   _largest = _objects.Max(x => x.Width);

   var size = _rand.Next(100, 100);

   using (var bmp = new Bitmap(size, size, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
   {
      var bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, size, size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
      var data = (int*)bitmapData.Scan0;
      Generate(new Size(size, size), data, 1);
      bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
      bmp.Save(@"D:\TestImage.bmp");
   }
}
```

**Test 100x100 5 blocks 1 padding**

[image]

[image]

**Test 100x100 5 blocks 2 padding**

[image]

**Test 100x100 10 blocks 2 padding**

[image]

**Test 100x100 b25 locks 2 padding**

[image]

**Test  100x100 25 blocks 1 padding**

[image]

**Test  100x100  25 blocks 0 padding**

[image]

**Summary**

Ok the premise of this was

- To just move across the plane from `x` then `y`
- Determine the free space
- Get a list of objects that would fit
- Choose a random one
- Draw it

However, if you play with the specs (i.e random variables) you will find there are biases. That's to say, on the first row it can fit anything it likes. However, subsequent rows it will be limited so it will bias to smaller blocks. And then towards the far extents it will bias to the smallest blacks to fill the image.

Also there is a bias towards a diagonal effect, this is basically just a result of the trying to fit in random blocks on the next line.

There are probably more micro optimizations to make this faster, however it is pretty good and works in milliseconds

Anyway, i guess this is a good starting point and you can add pepper and salt to taste

Good luck